# Creating past transactions without affecting current checking account balance

Tags: gnucash

I have started to use GnuCash as my main accounting software and I have created a brand new file with my current checking account balance. What I would like to do now is insert my past 2 months history of transactions in order to analyse where money went and came from.

The problem I am facing is that, even if I insert a past transaction the software reduces the balance of my current checking account (which is in the future relative to the transaction).

What I would like the software to do is something similar to this:

> If on date 12/12/12 you had a current balance in checking account of 1000$ and you insert a transaction on date 10/12/12 of 50$, that means that before 10/12/12 you had 1050$.

Is there a way to *fix* my current checking account and create past transactions *relative* to my current checking account balance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that that the first entry in the software involved a starting balance for the account. This is a fake entry.

Lets say you decided that you wanted to start tracking your finances on January first 2022. You needed to have a fake entry on 31 December 2021, to have the correct starting balance. The amount would be the starting balance on January 1st. Now you wanted to start 3 months earlier to capture all your holiday expenses. That would mean that you need to alter the fake entry. The date is wrong and the amount is wrong. The date would now be 30 September, and the amount would be the starting balance from 01 October 2021.

Comment: So it's not possible I guess, or at least it's not meant to be used like that.

Comment: @Matt That is not what mhoran said. He said: it is possible, and to do what you want to do, you just have to do the following: <his answer>.